# createSelector of reselect: does it do deep comparison for nested object?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reselect

What if `second`(nested object) changes in redux?
If it do shallow comparison it should ignore the change and not re-render.

All the example I see in doc, they are based on a simple object, where shallow compare is ok.

```
// assume state is:  {data: {first : {second { } } }}

const selectData = state => state.data;

const selectSecond = createSelector(
    selectData,
    data => data
);
```

Comment: All updates to `state` are immutable, so if `second` is changed then `first` and `data` will also be new objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`createSelector` uses [strict equality (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality), which means that two objects are considered "equal" if and only if they are references to the same object in memory.  This the same type of check that React uses when comparing `state` or comparing `useEffect` dependencies.

Shallow equality means that two objects are equal if all of their properties are strictly equal.

Deep equality means that two objects are equal if their contents are the same, regardless of object references.  It is computationally expensive and almost never needed in React or Redux due to the immutable nature of data.

---

Redux state is considered immutable so you should never have a situation where an object is the same reference in memory but has different contents.  Every time that a property changes, you must create a new object.  If `second` has changed, then `first` and `data` will be new objects.

> What if 'second' (nested object) change in redux? If it do shallow comparison it should ignore the change and not rerender.

You would only have this problem if you made a mutation in your state.  As long as your reducer is correct then you will get rerenders whenever `state.data` changes because any change at all requires creating a new object.

---

Here's a few examples of the various equality checks:

```
state => state
```

`state` is strict equal, shallow equal, and deep equal.

```
state => ({...state})
```

`state` is shallow equal and deep equal.  It is not strict equal because it is a new object.

```
state => ({...state, nested: {...state.nested}})
```

`state` is deep equal.  It is not strict equal or shallow equal because the `nested` property is a new object.

```
state => ({...state, number: 5})
```

`state` has a changed property so it fails all equality checks.

```
state => {
  state.nested.number = 5;
  return state;
}
```

This is the sort of mutation that is not allowed in React or Redux.  `state` is strict equal because we returned the same `state` object.  It is also shallow equal because `state.nested` is the same object.  It is not deep equal (unless the value was 5 before).

```
state => {
  state.nested = 5;
  return state;
}
```

Again this is not allowed.  If you mutate a top-level property then `state` is strict equal but not shallow equal or deep equal.

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation, it did clear several concepts.
Yes we are using this pattern `state => ({...state, nested: {...state.nested}})`

So my understanding after your feedback:
1)  **createSelector** default equality check is sufficient if nested object updated and there is no need to deep/shallow compare.

2) with **useSelector** we should use shallowEqual as second argument, and deep comparison like  lodash.isEqual is not needed.

3) Simply we don't need deep comparison with createSelector Or useSelector if redux state is properly immutable. 
Did i get it right ?

Comment: _"you should never have a situation where an object is the same reference in memory but has different contents"_ You _can't_ have such situation pretty much by definition, and you definitely can't have it in JS. Being mutable or not doesn't change it.

Comment: @Frax yeah I see how my wording there might be a bit off.  I'm referring to differences in the object from one render to the next.  Obviously at the same moment in time there only exists one object with one set of contents.